# How can a reduce a key value pair to key and list of values?

Tags: python, list, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

Let us Assume, I have a key value pair in Spark, such as the following.

```
[ (Key1, Value1), (Key1, Value2), (Key1, Vaue3), (Key2, Value4), (Key2, Value5) ]
```

Now I want to reduce this, to something like this.

```
[ (Key1, [Value1, Value2, Value3]), (Key2, [Value4, Value5]) ]
```

That is, from Key-Value to Key-List of Values.

How can I do that using the map and reduce functions in python or scala?

Comment: So you want a Spark solution in either Scala or Python or a plain Scala | Python solution? in other words is your starting collection an RDD ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce a key-value pair into a key-list pair with Apache Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002161/reduce-a-key-value-pair-into-a-key-list-pair-with-apache-spark)

Comment: What a mess. Why is it tagged with both `scala` and `python`...

Answer (score 4):

`collections.defaultdict` can be the solution https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, value in [('Key1', 'Value1'), ('Key1', 'Value2'), ('Key1', 'Vaue3'), ('Key2', 'Value4'), ('Key2', 'Value5') ]:
...     d[key].append(value)

>>> print d.items()
[('Key2', ['Value4', 'Value5']), ('Key1', [ 'Value1','Value2', 'Vaue3'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val data = Seq(("Key1", "Value1"), ("Key1", "Value2"), ("Key1", "Vaue3"), ("Key2", "Value4"), ("Key2", "Value5"))

data
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))

res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[String]] =
     Map(
        Key2 -> List(Value4, Value5), 
        Key1 -> List(Value1, Value2, Vaue3))
```

Comment: Cool! However, the solution in python looks much easier.

Comment: @MetallicPriest this question is tagged with 'apache-spark', making this answer the only correct one to run on Spark. Are you running this on Spark?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more readable way to do this, but the first thing that comes to mind is using `itertools.groupby`. Sort the list by the first element of the tuple (the key). Then use a list comprehension to iterate over the groups.

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [('key1', 1),('key1', 2),('key1', 3),('key2', 4),('key2', 5)]
l.sort(key = lambda i : i[0])

[(key, [i[1] for i in values]) for key, values in groupby(l, lambda i: i[0])]
```

Output

```
[('key1', [1, 2, 3]), ('key2', [4, 5])]
```

Comment: This relies on the keys being sorted

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
newlist = dict()
for x in l: 
    if x[0] not in newlist: 
        dict[x[0]] = list()
    dict[x[0]].append(x[1])
```

Comment: You can use `defaultdict(list)` to simplify

Answer (score 0):

The shortest, using the defaultdict, is the following; no requirements on being sorted.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict                                                                                       
>>> collect = lambda tuplist: reduce(lambda acc, (k,v): acc[k].append(v) or acc,\
                                     tuplist, defaultdict(list))
>>> collect( [(1,0), (2,0), (1,2), (2,3)])
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 3]})
```

Comment: While I can appreciate the functional style, using it just to call a function with side-effects looks a bit odd

Comment: Main reason to write it like this is that the code does not rely on modification of a variable in the outer scope. I'm not sure which side effect you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Another scala one, avoiding groupBy/mapValues (although that's the obvious Scala solution this one follows the python one given by Vishni since @MetallicPriest commented that was "much easier")

```
val data = Seq(("Key1", "Value1"), ("Key1", "Value2"), ("Key1", "Vaue3"),
               ("Key2", "Value4"), ("Key2", "Value5"))

val dict = Map[String, Seq[String]]() withDefaultValue(Nil)

data.foldLeft(dict){ case (d, (k,v)) => d updated (k, d(k) :+ v) }

// Map(Key1 -> List(Value1, Value2, Vaue3), Key2 -> List(Value4, Value5))
```

(Does an append of the key to give the exact results of the question. Prepend would be more efficient, though)

Mutable version, even closer to the Python one:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map, Seq}
val dict = Map[String, Seq[String]]() withDefaultValue(Seq())

for ((k,v) <- data) dict(k) :+= v
dict
// Map(Key2 -> ArrayBuffer(Value4, Value5),
//     Key1 -> ArrayBuffer(Value1, Value2, Vaue3))
```