# Reduce a key-value pair into a key-list pair with Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, rdd

I am writing a Spark application and want to combine a set of Key-Value pairs `(K, V1), (K, V2), ..., (K, Vn)` into one Key-Multivalue pair `(K, [V1, V2, ..., Vn])`. I feel like I should be able to do this using the `reduceByKey` function with something of the flavor:

```
My_KMV = My_KV.reduce(lambda a, b: a.append([b]))
```

The error that I get when this occurs is:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribue 'append'.

My keys are integers and values V1,...,Vn are tuples.  My goal is to create a single pair with the key and a list of the values (tuples).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Map and ReduceByKey**

Input type and output type of `reduce` must be the same, therefore if you want to aggregate a list, you have to `map` the input to lists. Afterwards you combine the lists into one list.

**Combining lists**

You'll need a method to combine lists into one list. Python provides some [methods to combine lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/199048).

`append` modifies the first list and will always return `None`.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append([4, 5])
# x is [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

`extend` does the same, but unwraps lists:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.extend([4, 5])
# x is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Both methods return `None`, but you'll need a method that returns the combined list, therefore just [use the plus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720432).

```
x = [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5]
# x is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**Spark**

```
file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
counts = file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
         .map(lambda actor: (actor.split(",")[0], actor)) \ 

         # transform each value into a list
         .map(lambda nameTuple: (nameTuple[0], [ nameTuple[1] ])) \

         # combine lists: ([1,2,3] + [4,5]) becomes [1,2,3,4,5]
         .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

---

**CombineByKey**

It's also possible to solve this with `combineByKey`, which is used internally to implement `reduceByKey`, but it's more complex and [*"using one of the specialized per-key combiners in Spark can be much faster"*](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html). Your use case is simple enough for the upper solution.

**GroupByKey**

It's also possible to solve this with `groupByKey`, [but it reduces parallelization](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) and therefore could be much slower for big data sets.

Comment: Is ReduceByKey in this case faster than GroupByKey? It produces the same result, so which is better? Is there a way to remove duplicates from the final list produced by ReduceByKey?

Comment: @Sofia: As said, *GroupByKey* reduces parallelization, but if you're working with small data sets, that might not be a problem. Only a performance test can give you a specific answer. Removing duplicate values isn't built-in when using *ReduceByKey*, but you could easily add another step which does that or create your own *Create* method which takes care about it.

Comment: Oops, I meant "you can create your own *Combine* method".

Comment: Using `+` forces the growing list to be copied on every append, taking time quadratic in the final length of each list.  `extend()` is the right answer--you wrap it in a function that returns the (growing) left-hand-side `list`.

Comment: Will the order of the list be maintained?

Comment: @ascetic652: no, you could sort the items in the reduce step. Normally when working with big data sets you don't sort data during computation. You could store the results in a database and only sort them when querying from the front end.

Comment: GroupByKey is the correct solution here. People often misuse GroupByKey followed by Map to imitate ReduceByKey in an inefficient manner which is why GroupByKey is said to be less efficient than ReduceByKey. However, this is exactly the problem for which GroupByKey as been designed and optimized for and therefore for this problem it is actually the good solution.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer How to do with ReduceByKey or  CombineByKey what if i want to sort the list? My scenario is doing subtract between two RDDs, so i have to sort the list.

Answer (score 20):

**tl;dr** If you really require operation like this use `groupByKey` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29845381/1560062) by [@MariusIon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967094/marius-ion). Every other solution proposed here is either bluntly inefficient are at least suboptimal compared to direct grouping.

`reduceByKey` with list concatenation is not an acceptable solution because:

- Requires initialization of *O(N)* lists.
- Each application of `+` to a pair of lists requires full copy of both lists (*O(N)*) effectively increasing overall complexity to *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*.
- Doesn't address any of the problems introduced by `groupByKey`. Amount of data that has to be shuffled as well as the size of the final structure are the same.
- Unlike [suggested by one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002657/1560062) there is no difference in a level of parallelism between implementation using `reduceByKey` and `groupByKey`.

`combineByKey` with `list.extend` is a suboptimal solution because:

- Creates *O(N)* list objects in `MergeValue` (this could be optimized by using `list.append` directly on the new item).
- If optimized with `list.append` it is exactly equivalent to an old (Spark <= 1.3) implementation of a `groupByKey` and ignores all the optimizations introduced by SPARK-3074 which enables external (on-disk) grouping of the larger-than-memory structures.

Answer (score 15):

I'm kind of late to the conversation, but here's my suggestion:

```
>>> foo = sc.parallelize([(1, ('a','b')), (2, ('c','d')), (1, ('x','y'))])
>>> foo.map(lambda (x,y): (x, [y])).reduceByKey(lambda p,q: p+q).collect()
[(1, [('a', 'b'), ('x', 'y')]), (2, [('c', 'd')])]
```

Comment: Hi, can you also help with an `equivalent Java code` for this. I want to achieve a similar kind of thing in Java

Comment: `map(lambda (x,y): (x, [y]))` has solved the concatenation problem (instead of merging). Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the RDD [groupByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupByKey) method.

*Input:*

```
data = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'f')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
result = rdd.groupByKey().collect()
```

*Output:*

```
[(1, ['a', 'b']), (2, ['c', 'd', 'e']), (3, ['f'])]
```

Comment: Using `groupByKey` is discouraged because it leads to excessive shuffling. You should use `reduceByKey` ([see this link](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)) or `combineByKey` instead, as suggested by @Christian_Strempfer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a reduceByKey where the type in the reduced KV pairs is different than the type in the original KV pairs, then one can use the function `combineByKey`.  What the function does is take KV pairs and combine them (by Key) into KC pairs where C is a different type than V.

One specifies 3 functions, createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners.  The first specifies how to transform a type V into a type C, the second describes how to combine a type C with a type V, and the last specifies how to combine a type C with another type C.  My code creates the K-V pairs:

Define the 3 functions as follows:

```
def Combiner(a):    #Turns value a (a tuple) into a list of a single tuple.
    return [a]

def MergeValue(a, b): #a is the new type [(,), (,), ..., (,)] and b is the old type (,)
    a.extend([b])
    return a

def MergeCombiners(a, b): #a is the new type [(,),...,(,)] and so is b, combine them
    a.extend(b)
    return a
```

Then, `My_KMV = My_KV.combineByKey(Combiner, MergeValue, MergeCombiners)`

The best resource I found on using this function is: http://abshinn.github.io/python/apache-spark/2014/10/11/using-combinebykey-in-apache-spark/

As others have pointed out, `a.append(b)` or `a.extend(b)` return `None`.  So the `reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a.append(b))` returns None on the first pair of KV pairs, then fails on the second pair because None.append(b) fails.  You could work around this by defining a separate function:

```
 def My_Extend(a,b):
      a.extend(b)
      return a
```

Then call `reduceByKey(lambda a, b: My_Extend(a,b))` (The use of the lambda function here may be unnecessary, but I have not tested this case.)

Answer (score 2):

The error message stems from the type for 'a' in your closure.

```
 My_KMV = My_KV.reduce(lambda a, b: a.append([b]))
```

Let pySpark explicitly evaluate a as a list. For instance,

```
My_KMV = My_KV.reduceByKey(lambda a,b:[a].extend([b]))
```

In many cases, reduceByKey will be preferable to groupByKey, refer to:
http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried with combineByKey ,here are my steps

```
combineddatardd=sc.parallelize([("A", 3), ("A", 9), ("A", 12),("B", 4), ("B", 10), ("B", 11)])

combineddatardd.combineByKey(lambda v:[v],lambda x,y:x+[y],lambda x,y:x+y).collect()
```

Output:

```
[('A', [3, 9, 12]), ('B', [4, 10, 11])]
```

1. Define a function for combiner which sets accumulator to first key value pair which it encounters inside the partition convert the value to list in this step
2. Define a function which mergers the new value  of the same key to the  accumulator value captured in step 1 Note:-convert the value to list in this function as accumulator value was converted to list in first step
3. Define function to merge combiners outputs of individual partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I hope, I got this right. Your input is something like this:

```
kv_input = [("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("b", 5)]
```

and you want to get something like this:

```
kmv_output = [("a", [1, 2, 3]), ("b", [1, 5])]
```

Then this might do the job (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)):

```
d = dict()
for k, v in kv_input:
    d.setdefault(k, list()).append(v)
kmv_output = list(d.items())
```

If I got this wrong, please tell me, so I might adjust this to your needs.

P.S.: `a.append([b])` returns always `None`. You might want to observe either `[b]` or `a` but not the result of `append`.

Comment: So you have exactly the right idea for what I have, in terms of kv_input, and what I want, kmv_output.  I believe your code would work find for serial python, but because I'm using Spark to do thing in parallel, my kv_input has type RDD (Resilient Distributed Data)... which is not iterable (so I cannot do something like for k,v in kv_input).

Comment: ahh. ok. my fault, don't know spark. I let the answer here for those who don't know/notice that. like me :P

Comment: No worries.  I'm quite new to it and I appreciate that you took the time to demonstrate this solution.

Comment: The P.S. is very helpful.  I did a quick change to retList = a.append([b]) then return retList and this fixes the first problem, but I have a new minor problem which I should be able to fix (the code generates a list which contains both tuples and lists).

Comment: @TravisJ: You need to use `extend` instead of `append`, like I did in my answer. See also [Python - append vs. extend](http://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/199048).

Answer (score 0):

I hit this page while looking for java example for the same problem. (If your case is similar, here is my example)

The trick is - You need to group for keys.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class SparkMRExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // spark context initialisation
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("WordCount")
                .setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        //input for testing;
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
                "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
                "It has survived not only for centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
                "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing");
        JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = context.parallelize(input);


        // the map phase of word count example
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> mappedRDD =
                inputRDD.flatMapToPair( line ->                      // for this input, each string is a line
                        Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))            // splitting into words, converting into stream
                                .map(word -> new Tuple2<>(word, 1))  // each word is assigned with count 1
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()));      // stream to iterable

        // group the tuples by key
        // (String,Integer) -> (String, Iterable<Integer>)
        JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Integer>> groupedRDD = mappedRDD.groupByKey();

        // the reduce phase of word count example
        //(String, Iterable<Integer>) -> (String,Integer)
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Integer>> resultRDD =
                groupedRDD.map(group ->                                      //input is a tuple (String, Iterable<Integer>)
                        new Tuple2<>(group._1,                              // the output key is same as input key
                        StreamSupport.stream(group._2.spliterator(), true)  // converting to stream
                                .reduce(0, (f, s) -> f + s)));              // the sum of counts
        //collecting the RRD so that we can print
        List<Tuple2<String, Integer>> result = resultRDD.collect();
        // print each tuple
        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have input data like this

```
10 1
10 2
20 4
20 7
20 9
```

And you want the output something like this

```
10-1,2
20-4,7,9
```

You can do something like this

```
rdd=sc.textFile("location_of_file") 

def parse(line):
    fields=line.split(" ")
    return (fields[0],fields[1])

rdd1=rdd.map(parse) //parse func is for having the input as key,value pair
rdd1.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).