# Pyspark creating nested field by partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with a format like:

```
id | product
-------------
1  | A
1  | B
1  | C
2  | A
3  | A
3  | C
```

What I want to accomplish is a 2 column data frame output where there is one row per ID with an array for every product owned by that ID. I tried some code with mapPartitions() but I get errors about not being able to infer schema. I know I have to yield something back in the map function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Using Spark 1.6

**Edit**

In case anyone else has this question, I actually went with the solution here using combineByKey():
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043562/1181412

It gave more flexibility to work the fields in a more granular way

Comment: I'm actually going to go with this one as it seems to get me a step closer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit clunky but works

```
a = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
            (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), 
            (2, 'A'), 
            (3, 'A'), (3, 'C')]), ['id', 'product']) 

sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    a.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + ',' + y), 
    ['id', 'products']).show()
```