# Scala - List[MyObject] -> Map[Long, List[Long]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm very new to scala and am trying to achieve the following:

I have a list of objects like so:

```
groups = [{id=1, iq=2}, {id=1,iq=3}, {id=2, iq=4}]
```

How can build a map[Long,List[Long]] from groups?

eg.

```
[{1, [2,3]}, {2,[4]}]
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a reduce a key value pair to key and list of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780348/how-can-a-reduce-a-key-value-pair-to-key-and-list-of-values) (Specifically [Sergey Lagutin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26780440/2707792))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` method. Here's an example in a REPL session:

```
scala> case class MyObject(id: Long, iq: Long)
defined class MyObject

scala> val xs = List(MyObject(1, 2), MyObject(1, 3), MyObject(2, 4))
xs: List[MyObject] = List(MyObject(1,2), MyObject(1,3), MyObject(2,4))

scala> val groupedById = xs.groupBy(_.id)
groupedById: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Long,List[MyObject]] = Map(2 -> List(MyObject(2,4)), 1 -> List(MyObject(1,2), MyObject(1,3)))

scala> val idToIqs = groupedById.mapValues(_.map(_.iq))
idToIqs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Long,List[Long]] = Map(2 -> List(4), 1 -> List(2, 3))
```

I used an intermediate value, `groupedById`, so you can see what happens along the way.

Comment: Great answer and really well explained. Thank you kindly.